# Объясните как создать статическую библиотеку в qt и как её использовать

Tags: qt

Может есть ресурс где это можно посотреть или что то в этом роде. Не могу никак найти подходящей инфы как это делать и как использовать. Мне бы пример такого типа: Так создаем, тут пишем, так используем.

Comment: https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_create_a_library_with_Qt_and_use_it_in_an_application/ru

Answer (score 0):

Создайте тестовый проект с `MainWindow`. Затем сформируйте дерево каталогов такого вида:

```
myapp
|_myapp.pro
  |_app
   |_app.pro
   |_main.cpp
  |_lib
    |_mainwindow.pro
    |_mainwindow.cpp
    |_mainwindow.h
    |_mainwindow.ui
```

Главный файл проекта `myapp.pro` имеет следующее содержание:

```
# говорим, что наш огромный проект состоит из подпроектов
TEMPLATE = subdirs
# а именно lib и app
SUBDIRS  = lib app

# явно указываем pro-файлы этих проектов
lib.file = lib/mainwindow.pro
app.file = app/app.pro
# и говорим, что app зависит от lib
app.depends = lib
```

Далее содержимое `mainwindow.pro`:

```
QT += core gui
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets
# название файла нашей статической библиотеки
TARGET = mainwindow
# указываем, что проект не запускаемой приложение, а библиотека
TEMPLATE = lib
# какая? статическая
CONFIG += staticlib
# заметьте, тут нет main.cpp
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS
SOURCES += mainwindow.cpp
HEADERS += mainwindow.h
FORMS += mainwindow.ui
```

Ну и наконец `app.pro`:

```
QT       += core gui
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = myappexe
# теперь это запускаемое приложение
TEMPLATE = app

DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

# говорим, где смотреть заголовочные файлы
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../lib
# и где искать символы статической библиотеки
# префикс -L - для указания пути где искать библиотеки
# префикс -l перед названием самой библиотеки
LIBS += -L$$OUT_PWD/../lib -lmainwindow

# а тут только main.cpp и всё
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

Домашнее задание - создать подпроект `tests`, где реализовать тесты для `MainWindow`.

Comment: Здравствуйте, создал статическую бибилотеку, использую 1 объявление и 2 реализации функций для разных систем, сейчас выдает такую ошибку что делать ? Скриншоты прикрепил выше

Comment: @DanBit что в ошибке сказано?

Comment: Для того, чтобы Ваш ответ был полным необходимо еще добfвить main.cpp, в котором будет понятно как инклюдиться "mainwindow.h" и как вызываются функции из библиотеки.